# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a los datos de este JSON?

Tags: php, json

Quiero saber como puedo acceder al código de este json con php.

```
[{
  "GameId": 53614,
  "Season": 2018,
  "SeasonType": 1,
  "Day": "2018-09-28T00:00:00",
  "DateTime": "2018-09-28T14:10:00",
  "Status": "InProgress",
  "AwayTeamId": 16,
  "HomeTeamId": 20,
  "AwayTeamName": "CHW",
  "HomeTeamName": "MIN",
  "GlobalGameId": 10053614,
  "GlobalAwayTeamId": 10000016,
  "GlobalHomeTeamId": 10000020,
  "PregameOdds": [{
    "GameOddId": 509945,
    "Sportsbook": "BetDSI",
    "GameId": 53614,
    "Created": "2018-09-28T14:12:36",
    "Updated": "2018-09-28T16:27:12",
    "HomeMoneyLine": -185,
    "AwayMoneyLine": 169,
    "HomePointSpread": -1.7,
    "AwayPointSpread": 1.7,
    "HomePointSpreadPayout": 140,
    "AwayPointSpreadPayout": -163,
    "OverUnder": 9.0,
    "OverPayout": -123,
    "UnderPayout": -123
  }],
  "LiveOdds": []
}]
```

Comment: Queres recorrerlo en php o en javascript?

Comment: En PHP ya hice el Json_decode con php quiero acceder a los datos que estan dentro de ese json

Comment: utiliza un `foreach`

Comment: No se como hacerlo, por eso pido ayuda

Comment: Edite la respuesta por favor revisa si te sirbe

Answer (score 0):

Aunque ese tu array esta mero raro, de donde lo obtienes?
Intenta con esto

```
$array = 'a tu array';

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
   echo $value
}
```

Respuesta editada:
Bueno esto es tu json:

```
$json = '[{
   "GameId": 53614,
   "Season": 2018,
   "SeasonType": 1,
   "Day": "2018-09-28T00:00:00",
   "DateTime": "2018-09-28T14:10:00",
   "Status": "InProgress",
   "AwayTeamId": 16,
   "HomeTeamId": 20,
   "AwayTeamName": "CHW",
   "HomeTeamName": "MIN",
   "GlobalGameId": 10053614,
   "GlobalAwayTeamId": 10000016,
   "GlobalHomeTeamId": 10000020,
   "PregameOdds": [{
      "GameOddId": 509945,
      "Sportsbook": "BetDSI",
      "GameId": 53614,
      "Created": "2018-09-28T14:12:36",
      "Updated": "2018-09-28T16:27:12",
      "HomeMoneyLine": -185,
      "AwayMoneyLine": 169,
      "HomePointSpread": -1.7,
      "AwayPointSpread": 1.7,
      "HomePointSpreadPayout": 140,
      "AwayPointSpreadPayout": -163,
      "OverUnder": 9.0,
      "OverPayout": -123,
      "UnderPayout": -123
   }],
   "LiveOdds": []
}]';
```

convertir json a array

```
$array = json_decode($json,true);
```

este es el array

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:15 [▼
    "GameId" => 53614
    "Season" => 2018
    "SeasonType" => 1
    "Day" => "2018-09-28T00:00:00"
    "DateTime" => "2018-09-28T14:10:00"
    "Status" => "InProgress"
    "AwayTeamId" => 16
    "HomeTeamId" => 20
    "AwayTeamName" => "CHW"
    "HomeTeamName" => "MIN"
    "GlobalGameId" => 10053614
    "GlobalAwayTeamId" => 10000016
    "GlobalHomeTeamId" => 10000020
    "PregameOdds" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:14 [▼
        "GameOddId" => 509945
        "Sportsbook" => "BetDSI"
        "GameId" => 53614
        "Created" => "2018-09-28T14:12:36"
        "Updated" => "2018-09-28T16:27:12"
        "HomeMoneyLine" => -185
        "AwayMoneyLine" => 169
        "HomePointSpread" => -1.7
        "AwayPointSpread" => 1.7
        "HomePointSpreadPayout" => 140
        "AwayPointSpreadPayout" => -163
        "OverUnder" => 9.0
        "OverPayout" => -123
        "UnderPayout" => -123
      ]
    ]
    "LiveOdds" => []
  ]
]
```

si te puedes dar cuenta, tiene un indice 0, a causa de eso debes hacer esto:

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
{
   echo ($v['GameId']);
   echo ($v['Season']);
   echo ($v['SeasonType']);
   echo ($v['Day']);
   echo ($v['DateTime']);
   //..cuando llegues a PregameOdds este es otro array, entonces debes hacer esto
   echo ($v['PregameOdds'][0]['GameOddId']);
   //...etc   
}
```

Comment: Lo siento, no funciona!

Comment: Por eso te pregunto de donde traes la información de ese json

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta con el Json que me estan proporcionadno. quiero accader a esos valores desde php

Answer (score 0):

```
                            <script>
                                $(document).ready(function () {
                                    var json1 = <?php print_r($rest) ?>;/* en la variable $rest Obtengo el json ya procesado para mostrar los datos*/
                                    var tr;
                                    var a = 1; /*contador para poder tener identificado cada parametro de la consulta*/
                                    var b = 1; /*contador para poder tener identificado cada parametro de la consulta*/
                                    for (var i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {/*va recorriendo los datos consultados*/
                                        tr = $('<tr/>');
                                        tr.append('<td id="nombre_'+a+'" name="nombre_'+a+'">' + json1[i].key + '</td>');
                                        tr.append('<td id="precio_'+b+'" name="precio_'+b+'">' + json1[i].value + '</td>');            
                                        $('table').append(tr);                          
                                        a++;                          
                                        b++;

                                    } 
                                });

                            </script>
```

Prueba esto los campos son de acuerdo GameId, en ves de nombre, etc....

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta y coloque el codigo json como tal, quiero recorrer los datos usando PHP no javascript

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que te refieres a como poder convertir el `JSON` a un `array` para poder iterarlo o lo que quieras hacer.

```
$array = json_decode( $json, true );
```

El **true** es para indicarle que los objetos devueltos serán convertidos a `array` asociativos.

Puedes encontrar más información acerca de ésta función en:
[php.net](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)

Posteriormente, una vez que ya tengas el `array`, puedes iterarlo con `foreach` o cualquier otra opción, como bien han indicado arriba.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo que quiero hacer es una vez echo el json_decode, poder recorrer los datos que estan dentro de ese json como por ejemplo: echo $array->GameId, he intentado eso pero no funciona.

Comment: ten en cuenta que tu json es un array de objetos. Por lo tanto, primero tienes que acceder al primer objeto, y luego a los elementos. En tu caso, una vez decodificado con json_decode, puedes acceder con el indice 0 y luego la clave asociada. Por ej: `$valores[0]('HomeTeamId');`

Answer (score 0):

Hice un pequeño código funcional donde puede guiarte, si ves dentro del código coloque un `foreach` para recorrer el **array** en dado caso si tienes mas de un indice en ese array json y la otra acceder directamente seteando el indice si siempre quieres acceder a uno solo:

[Ejemplo funcional de como obtener un valor array json](http:////phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn$array%20=%20'[%7B%5Cn%22GameId%22:%2053614,%5Cn%22Season%22:%202018,%5Cn%22SeasonType%22:%201,%5Cn%22Day%22:%20%222018-09-28T00:00:00%22,%5Cn%22DateTime%22:%20%222018-09-28T14:10:00%22,%5Cn%22Status%22:%20%22InProgress%22,%5Cn%22AwayTeamId%22:%2016,%5Cn%22HomeTeamId%22:%2020,%5Cn%22AwayTeamName%22:%20%22CHW%22,%5Cn%22HomeTeamName%22:%20%22MIN%22,%5Cn%22GlobalGameId%22:%2010053614,%5Cn%22GlobalAwayTeamId%22:%2010000016,%5Cn%22GlobalHomeTeamId%22:%2010000020,%5Cn%22PregameOdds%22:%20[%7B%5Cn%22GameOddId%22:%20509945,%5Cn%22Sportsbook%22:%20%22BetDSI%22,%5Cn%22GameId%22:%2053614,%5Cn%22Created%22:%20%222018-09-28T14:12:36%22,%5Cn%22Updated%22:%20%222018-09-28T16:27:12%22,%5Cn%22HomeMoneyLine%22:%20-185,%5Cn%22AwayMoneyLine%22:%20169,%5Cn%22HomePointSpread%22:%20-1.7,%5Cn%22AwayPointSpread%22:%201.7,%5Cn%22HomePointSpreadPayout%22:%20140,%5Cn%22AwayPointSpreadPayout%22:%20-163,%5Cn%22OverUnder%22:%209.0,%5Cn%22OverPayout%22:%20-123,%5Cn%22UnderPayout%22:%20-123%5Cn%7D],%5Cn%22LiveOdds%22:%20[]%5Cn%7D]';%5Cn$array%20=%20(array)json_decode($array);%5Cn//Este%20seria%20si%20tuvieses%20mas%20de%20un%20indice%20dentro%20de%20tu%20json%20array%5Cnforeach($array%20as%20$clave%20=%3E%20$valor)%7B%5Cn%20echo%20'GameId%20=%20'.$valor-%3EGameId.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%20echo%20'Season%20=%20'.$valor-%3ESeason.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%20echo%20'DateTime%20=%20'.$valor-%3EDateTime.'%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%20if(is_array($valor-%3EPregameOdds))%7B%5Cn%20foreach($valor-%3EPregameOdds%20as%20$clave2%20=%3E%20$valor2)%7B%5Cn%20echo%20'GameOddId%20=%20'.$valor2-%3EGameOddId.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%20echo%20'Sportsbook%20=%20'.$valor2-%3ESportsbook.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%20echo%20'Created%20=%20'.$valor2-%3ECreated.'%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn%20%7D;%5Cn%20%7D;%5Cn%7D;%5Cn//Este%20seria%20si%20siempre%20accederias%20al%20primer%20indice%20de%20tu%20array%5Cnecho%20'GameId%20=%20'.$array[0]-%3EGameId.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cnecho%20'Season%20=%20'.$array[0]-%3ESeason.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cnecho%20'DateTime%20=%20'.$array[0]-%3EDateTime.'%3Cbr%3E';%5Cn?%3E)

```
<?php

    $array = '[{
                "GameId": 53614,
                "Season": 2018,
                "SeasonType": 1,
                "Day": "2018-09-28T00:00:00",
                "DateTime": "2018-09-28T14:10:00",
                "Status": "InProgress",
                "AwayTeamId": 16,
                "HomeTeamId": 20,
                "AwayTeamName": "CHW",
                "HomeTeamName": "MIN",
                "GlobalGameId": 10053614,
                "GlobalAwayTeamId": 10000016,
                "GlobalHomeTeamId": 10000020,
                "PregameOdds": [{
                     "GameOddId": 509945,
                     "Sportsbook": "BetDSI",
                     "GameId": 53614,
                     "Created": "2018-09-28T14:12:36",
                     "Updated": "2018-09-28T16:27:12",
                     "HomeMoneyLine": -185,
                     "AwayMoneyLine": 169,
                     "HomePointSpread": -1.7,
                     "AwayPointSpread": 1.7,
                     "HomePointSpreadPayout": 140,
                     "AwayPointSpreadPayout": -163,
                     "OverUnder": 9.0,
                     "OverPayout": -123,
                     "UnderPayout": -123
               }],
               "LiveOdds": []
             }]';

    $array = (array)json_decode($array);

    //Este seria si tuvieses mas de un indice dentro de tu json array
    foreach($array as $clave => $valor){
      echo 'GameId = '.$valor->GameId.'<br>';
      echo 'Season = '.$valor->Season.'<br>';
      echo 'DateTime = '.$valor->DateTime.'<br><br>';

      if(is_array($valor->PregameOdds)){

        foreach($valor->PregameOdds as $clave2 => $valor2){
          echo 'GameOddId = '.$valor2->GameOddId.'<br>';
          echo 'Sportsbook = '.$valor2->Sportsbook.'<br>';
          echo 'Created = '.$valor2->Created.'<br><br>';
        };

      };

    };

    //Este seria si siempre accederias al primer indice de tu array
    echo 'GameId = '.$array[0]->GameId.'<br>';
    echo 'Season = '.$array[0]->Season.'<br>';
    echo 'DateTime = '.$array[0]->DateTime.'<br>';

?>
```